# Best way to store multiple content types in SQL Server that are displayed on a single list

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, data-structures, database-schema

I have a .net application that will display many content types in a single view for a user , in a card listing. These cards would be displayed in a chronological order and have different layouts and display different information. They could be checklists, events, news, reminders etc.

Since I would like to get them fast from the database I do not think combining different tables is a good idea but at the same time, each of them would have different fields to be stored and displayed.

What is a good strategy to store this in a organized way on the database but still be able to query it fast.

Thanks!

Comment: so the only thing they have in common is that they are a card and probably share a few columns?  Yeah multiple tables seems like the best as they are different classes of a base class.  if you combine this into a single table what are you thinking just 100s of columns and that are nullable based on a type?  it will be easier logically to maintain the queries and data separately and you may realize data size savings as well.

Comment: You could store class instances serialized as XML in a simple table `Entities ( id int, xml thing )`, then have a tag table `Tags ( EntityID int, Name varchar, Value varchar )` or something to store searchable metadata. Maybe include a `TypeName` column in `Entities` as well.

Comment: Unclear/too broad... DBs are generally can handle "multiple" of whatever items you want... You may want to clarify why you can't store information in a way that is easy to access.

Comment: I just want ideas of a good way to store that are both easy to work with and also has a good performance when querying the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not a good solution for this kind of model. You'll want to look at a document store like ElasticSearch or MongoDB. Those are designed specifically for what you want to do.

I prefer ElasticSearch over MongoDB since the syntax is much cleaner IMO. ElasticSearch is also much, much, much faster then SQL on a fraction of the hardware for searches.

In order to do it fast in SQL, you'd need to have it in a flat table and you'd end up with lots of NULL columns for the properties that aren't valid for a specific item.